# (SQL) Titles in caps lock

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am aware of "[Whether we should be CAP COPs](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/whether-we-should-be-cap-cops)", however would like to ask for a special exception regarding titles. The reason for this is that for example right now on the entire SE network users see the following:

[image: Near entire title in caps lock]

And even within this specific site it looks terrible in lists. Additionally if you take into account that [the majority of the users *seems* to prefer lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292026/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-upper-case-for-sql-keywords) it seems quite reasonable to request that at least the number of caps in titles would be kept limited (possibly automated).

Comment: Nothing seems terrible to me. I could imagine other similar titles: `CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD OF UPDATE with ON CASCADE UPDATE`, `ADD PRIMARY KEY after CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX`, whatever. Perhaps the author just thought he'd express his idea better with commands (or partial commands). (And to point out they are keywords within a command rather than an example of poor grammar, he/she used upper case.)

Comment: On a case by case base, we can always edit and remove some of the capitals. For example this could be edited to: `SNAPSHOT isolation level vs. TRUNCATE`

Comment: @AndriyM: Maybe the part where the entire title is shouting at you...?

Comment: @ypercube: Yep, something along those lines I was hoping for, problem is that without community consensus it would seem bad practice to edit such a thing in light of the "CAP COPs" post. (especially as an outsider)

Comment: @DavidMulder If you don't have enough rep in the site, your suggested edit would have to pass through trusted users' check anyway. So, in any case, if you see a title that you think can be corrected to not shout so much, just suggest an edit.

Comment: FYI, don't take the downvotes on this Q as indicative of the quality of your question. Meta voting is meant to confer agreeing or disagreeing with the premise of the post.

Comment: As an aside, on the linked question most of the folks posting answers are not DBAs or database developers. I haven't met any yet who do majority TSQL coding that prefer lowercase keywords. Most of the major intellisense-type products (Redgate's SQL Prompt for instance) default to upper-case keywords.

Comment: @JNK: Regarding your aside, how is someone using SQL not a database developer (whatever that term might mean)? And the simple reasoning why these products use uppercase is that they are bound by tradition. A tradition that seems to be changing as supported by that question. Oh well, personally I don't care much whether it's upper case or not when coding myself, except when mixed with normal language ("`select` vs SELECT the records") and all over the StackExchange network.

Comment: Sorry I meant DB Developer as someone who does DB development pretty much full time (as I do). Honestly it is a personal preference thing, but this site in particular is geared more towards dedicated database folks. For me personally, if I see select and join in lowercase in tsql I fix it - most of the time that same code has bad spacing and indentation as well, so that could be why I'm prejudiced against it.

Answer (score 8):

My personal feeling on this is that the title in question is fine. Those are SQL keywords and in most circumstances are capitalized. The capitalization in the title makes it clear we are comparing two T-SQL commands, not just the concepts.

That being said I would find it acceptable to rewrite the title to use more natural language, i.e.

> What's the expected behavior of TRUNCATE using SNAPSHOT isolation?

...but not to edit it just to remove the caps.

However I don't think we can be prescriptive and say we never allow mostly-caps titles that use capitalized keywords.  One example I can think of that would be fine is

> UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or UNIQUE INDEX?

Comment: I'm seeing a ton of code where I work now that has the field names in all uppercase, and the keywords in lower case.  Drives me absolutely mad.  I cannot read that stuff.